# vue-cliでnpm run serveしたらエラーがでました。

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

`npm run serveコマンドを入力してプロジェクトを起動させるつもりがエラーがでてしましました。

```
> hello_app2@0.1.0 serve /Users/hogehoge/Mypage/vue-nuxt/ch01/hello_app2
> vue-cli-service serve

/Users/hogehoge/Mypage/vue-nuxt/ch01/hello_app2/node_modules/open/index.js:16
const wslToWindowsPath = async path => {
                               ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hogehoge/Mypage/vue-nuxt/ch01/hello_app2/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/openBrowser.js:9:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello_app2@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the hello_app2@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hogehoge/.npm/_logs/2019-12-07T11_56_17_151Z-debug.log
```

こちら
試してみたこと
https://teratail.com/questions/219324
nodeモジュールを再インストール

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install
```

変わらず詰まっています。

他にどういう解決法があるでしょうか?

Comment: 参考: [Cannot use it with node 6](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/305#issuecomment-485942887)

Comment: 前回の質問からするにnodebrewでv12系を使ってるように見えたのですが、一応念の為質問に`npm --versions` および`node -v`の出力を追記いただけると参考になりそうです。また、serveコマンドを打つまでにどういった操作を行ったかできるだけ詳しく書いてもらえると。どういったコマンドを打って構築した、どこどこのファイルをどう編集した、など。（エラー的には上のコメントで挙げられてるものとは思うのですが……）

Comment: 返答が遅くなりました。

開発バージョンは
node v12.13.1
npm v6.13.2

行ったコマンドは
npm install -g @vue/cli
npm install -g @vue/cli-service-global

プロジェクト作成
vue create hello_app
Enterですすめる

npm run serveを打つと上記のエラーとなります。

ちなみにyarn serveとうつときちんと表示されます。